# OpenSSL no crypto directory

Tags: linux, bios, ssl, openssl

I followed [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL) to setup self certified SSL on my server. 
but I face a problem when I sign the certificate as follows:

```
openssl ca -in tempreq.pem -out server_crt.pem
```

tutorial said you will then be prompted to confirm the information in the exampleserver.cnf but I got error as follows:

```
140394980766144:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72:fopen('/root/myCA/index.txt','r')
140394980766144:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79:
root@server:~/myCA# export OPENSSL_CONF=/root/myCA/caconfig.cnf
```

In fact, my server don't have /crypto directory so I search about "crypto" but I coundn't find about information.

How to countinue this tutorial?

Comment: It's trying (and failing) to find `/root/myCA/index.txt`

Comment: So is it mean I dont need to have  /crypto directory right now?

Comment: Have you tried `touch /root/myCA/index.txt` and seeing what happens? :-)

Comment: I create "index.txt" and "serial" directory(I got similar error after create index.txt). then I got this error.

unable to load number from /root/myCA/serial
error while loading serial number
140358020366784:error:0D066096:asn1 encoding routines:a2i_ASN1_INTEGER:short line:../crypto/asn1/f_int.c:140:

Comment: Did you put a double digit number in `serial`, such as `01`?